# 403 response Ionic 4 + Django Api rest on the same server?

Tags: django, ionic-framework

I built an Ionic 4 App which uses Django API REST endpoints.

The app has been tested on iPad and on my localhost using ionic-app-scripts serve.

Now I want to deploy it as a webapp, and I'm doing this by building for the browser platform (ionic cordova build browser --prod --release) and serving the index.html on the same Django App in which the API REST is on. Static files (js, assets, etc, are hosted on an Amazon S3 Bucket)

Now both on iPad and localhost I have no problems with the API REST POST requests. But when I run the app on the live server (even if the request is being sent from the same server than the API REST!!) I get 403...

The only difference I see when I compare the request Headers is that the one sent on the live server does not have an "Origin" parameter:

ON LIVE SERVER:

```
Accept  application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Cache-Control   no-cache
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Length  62
content-type     application/json
Cookie  _ga=GA1.2.1002502516.149305462…eay6lysy1w44vawa94lug20hpek2n
Host example.com
Pragma  no-cache
Referer http://example.com/front/
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel …) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0
```

ON LOCALHOST:

```
Accept  application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Length  62
content-type      application/json
Host      example.com
Origin  http://localhost:8100
Referer http://localhost:8100/
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel …) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0
```

Any ideas? I know there are several questions and posts regarding this topic, but generally the problem is the other way around (CORS issues when sending the posts from another domain)

(obviously example.com is no the real domain I'm using)

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, I had a Django authentication system in place and I was logged with that. When I logged out it worked correctly. It seems it was sending the csrf token with the cookies on the request and that caused a conflict.